# How to add tensorflow http_archive in bazel workspace?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

Not sure whether it is right way to ask this question or not?
I clone a sample project which depends on tensorflow and using http_archive as follows.

```
_TENSORFLOW_GIT_COMMIT = "84384703c0d8b502e33ff6fd7eefd219dca5ff8e"

_TENSORFLOW_SHA256 = "23fb322fc15a20f7a7838d9a31f8b16f60700a494ea654311a0aa8621769df98"

http_archive(
    name = "org_tensorflow",
    patch_args = [
        "-p1",
    ],
    patches = [
        "@//third_party:org_tensorflow_compatibility_fixes.diff",
    ],
    sha256 = _TENSORFLOW_SHA256,
    strip_prefix = "tensorflow-%s" % _TENSORFLOW_GIT_COMMIT,
    urls = [
        "https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/archive/%s.tar.gz" % _TENSORFLOW_GIT_COMMIT,
    ],
)
```

I need to change tensorflow version in above dependency. I can get commit id for specific commit from tensorflow get repository but don't know how to get hash sh256. I tried by changing commit id only in above dependency but bazel throws 404 exception. So my question is Do I actually need to provide another hash key for different git commit? If yes then how can I get Hash sh256 for specific commit?

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily remove the `sha256` argument, then Bazel will download the file and report the sha value.

Comment: removed the line `sha256 = _TENSORFLOW_SHA256,` so gives me `INFO: SHA256 (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/archive/82515cee8f36fe9f3abe25d5aef8218ce8bf48bb.tar.gz) = 67cdd7da47103fcfc9ce088cb945331a7d7d823fe9cf4bae333fef433257a260` & sync was fail. Next time I copied same SHA256 and added `sha256 = _TENSORFLOW_SHA256,` then again it fails with following error. `Error in patch: Error applying patch: $path ,the chunk content doesn't match the target
**Original Position**: 42` Any further comment may help? Thanks

Comment: Ah, then the patch is not compatible with the new version. Fixing that is pretty involved: check out tensorflow at the old version, apply the patch, merge in master, fix merge issues, then create a new patch...